# Break string into a list whose elements are strings of a certain length

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a string and I would like to break it in small strings of a fix size, storing the result in a list. I know that I can solve the task using a for loop, but the string is rather long, so I wonder if there is an efficient way to implement it.

The function must take as an input the string and the size of the the small strings.

For example:

```
input="abcdefghi"
size=3

Output=func(input, size)
```

The expected output would be:

```
Output=['abc','def','ghi']
```

If the length of the string is not a multiple of size, the length of the last element must be the rest of the division.

Comment: What would your result be if the length of the original string wasn't evenly divisible by `size`?

Comment: Also what code have you tried to solve this problem? It can easily be solved using a for loop and string splicing with a step but SO isn't here to solve your homework problems unless you at least show some effort. [What have you tried?](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I know that I can solve the task using a for loop, but I am looking for a way more efficient, because the string is very long

Comment: No matter what you do you will need a `for` loop such as `[s[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(s), size)]` where `s = "abcdefghi"` and `size = 3`. There is no way to do it in O(1) time no matter how much memory you consume and even if you use a built in from itertools it will use a `for` loop in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    def func(input_, size):
        input_ = list(input_)
        output = []
        for _ in range(len(input_)//size):
            output.append(input_[0:size])
            del(input_[0:size])
        return output
```

This function will return, in your case:

```
     [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```